# If I have to restart Chrome, tabs from months ago reload

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser

How can I get this to stop? They are MONTHS old and they take a long time to load and have nothing to do with what the most recent tabs were. Can you help me stop this?

Comment: Do you close all the tabs before restarting Chrome? What is setup in your On Start-up setting? Are you using the latest chrome version?

Comment: Sometimes I close all my tabs and sometimes I don't. But the most recent tabs were not coming back, only the ones from a year ago. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable the following?

1. Click the Chrome Menu More in upper right corner
2. Go to Settings
3. Under On startup, disable Continue where you left off

Comment: Tried this. Thank you for taking the time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like Chrome is opening a "set of pages".

Sometimes it gets stuck doing that.

Go to settings > On startup > Set pages and remove anything there.

Comment: This answer did the trick I think. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: please set the answer as useful, I have a reputation of 1 here )